# Unable to print the count value in the destination workbook

Tags: count

I don't have any error while running the below codes but its not print the result in the destination sheet. its just print 0 only

object workbook sheet  is have data and I'm using the specific column status with conditions

```
Sub Counts()
Dim objWorkbook As Workbook
'open the workbook with data
Set objWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("H:\TEST\July 2019 Tracker - Break Down & Travels.xlsx")

Dim i As Long
Dim GGV As Integer
GGV = 0

objWorkbook.Activate

For i = 1 To 1000

    If Sheet1.Cells(i, 20) = "GSC" And Sheet1.Cells(i, 21) = "Travel" Then
                GGV = GGV + 1
    End If

Next i
   'this work book
    Sheet4.Cells(6, 2) = GGV
    objWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

wanted to print the count value in this workbook